# The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm junior on flutter. Can someone help me?

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (message) async {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      showNotification(
        message['data'] != null
            ? message['data']['title'] ?? 'Service App'
            : 'Service App',
        message['data'] != null
            ? message['data']['body'] ?? 'Service App'
            : 'Service App',
      );
    },
    onResume: (message) async {
      print('onResume: $message');
    },
    onLaunch: (message) async {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no call to `configure` in the code you shared. Can you clarify what the exact error message is that you get, including the stack trace?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it turns out that it was removed on the flutter 2.0 version ^ and replaced with another one, I found a solution thank you.